# How to get to the returned object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, object, return

I'm having some problems with getting to the object which is returned by one method. To make it simple, for example:

```
var param = { }; // global variable
var url = 'some url which executes query';

function openURL(url) {

    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.onreadystatechange = handle_json;
     // Gets data in JSON format
    http_request.open("GET", url);
    http_request.send(null);


 function handle_json() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
                if (http_request.status == 200) {
                        var json_data = http_request.responseText; // gets text response
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);
                                                param = { lastID: obj.data };
                        if(obj.returnCodeDescription == null) {
                            //alert("Data updated!");
                        } else {
                            //alert("Error!");
                        }
                } else {
                        alert('There was some problems! Sorry!');
                }
                http_request = null;
        }
 }

 return param;

}
```

Now in some other method, let's say QueryResult() I would like to get to the variables which object param contains.

```
function QueryResult {

var query = 'some query here';
var result = openURL(url+query);

alert( ??? ); **// here I would like to display the value of param.lastID**

}
```

I really do not have any ideas how to make this work. Could anyone give me a hint which will help me to get the returned object from openURL method in QueryResult?

Comment: if you have param as a global you shouldnt have to return it to get access to the new values.  Also, are you sure that the code that assigns a value is getting run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous function is called when event accour - so it's after outer function is called. Try that:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/AAQqt/

```
function openURL(url, callback) {
    ...

    function handle_json() {
        ...

        callback(param);
    }
}


openURL(url, function(param){
    alert(param.lastID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an asynchronous function as if it was synchronous.

`openURL()` returns its value before `handle_json()` is called.

You can fix this by making openURL() an asynchronous function. So the function where you use openURL would be like this:

```
function QueryResult() {
  var query = 'some query here';
  var result = openURL(url+query, function(param) {
    alert( ??? ); **// here I would like to display the value of param.lastID**
  });
}
```

...and openURL() would be like this:

```
function openURL(url, callback) {

    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.onreadystatechange = handle_json;
     // Gets data in JSON format
    http_request.open("GET", url);
    http_request.send(null);


 function handle_json() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
                if (http_request.status == 200) {
                        var json_data = http_request.responseText; // gets text response
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);

                        // *instead of returning, call callback*
                        callback({ lastID: obj.data });

                        if(obj.returnCodeDescription == null) {
                            //alert("Data updated!");
                        } else {
                            //alert("Error!");
                        }
                } else {
                        alert('There was some problems! Sorry!');
                }
                http_request = null;
        }
 }
}
```